# How to prevent truncation in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am making an application to display movies sorted by Popularity and date.

When I click on a movie, it takes me to the description of the movie. I am using RelativeLayout for the description UI. But the movie name is truncated if its too large.

I have tried few solutions from stackoverflow for the textView like

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:lines="1"
```

I know there's one solution of using LinearLayout. But I wanted to know if there's a solution using RelativeLayout only.

[Please Find the screenshot by clicking on this link. The text gets truncated and its replaced by three dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drllr.jpg)

Here's the full code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_less"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_less"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_less"
        tools:context="com.example.puneet.movieout.MovieInfoDisplay"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Movie Title"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Movie name is Long. Movie name is Long"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Rating"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Rating"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Release Date"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overview"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please paste your entire xml layout.

Comment: You are setting the number of lines to 1,  what do you expect? Don't set that attribute.

Comment: @TudorLuca I am setting **lines = 1** and also **scrollHorizontally= true** along with it. So, that should technically display full text and in case it exceeds, I should be able to scroll to the right.

Comment: Hi @ShadabAnsari : i have added the code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to get the text truncated , you have to remove the  `ellipsize` attribute and add your `TextView` inside `HorizontalScrollView`.
Your view should be like :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/txt_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Movie name is Long. Movie name is Long"            
            android:id="@+id/textView2"          
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This way you can embed your text inside the scroll without the text being truncated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shadab . I appreciate that. Is there an attribute that I can change in that textView2, so that the remaining text can come in next line ?

Comment: But you wanted the text to be in 1 line and scrollable. That's why I suggested HorizontalScrollView. In case you want it o be multi line , the remove ellipsize and lines attribute and don't use HorizontalScrollView, you''ll get the text in multiline.